# JavaFX - adding a node to stack pane with same old X and Y

Tags: javafx

I have a stack pane positioned using an x and y on the screen, i start adding some nodes to the stack pane so the stack pane size increases, which now looks like that the stack pane is moving,,, this is difficult to make clear so here is an image that my explain more :

[image]

is there anyway to add a node to the stack pane and keep its original x and y ?

i am trying to do this without re-translating the location ,,, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used the default alignment of `StackPane`, which is `Pos.CENTER`, with the obvious effect that the `StackPane` will do it's best to keep the `Node` centered.

You can apply a different positioning for a single `Node`

```
StackPane.setAlignment(node, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
```

Or for the whole `StackPane`:

```
stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
```

With this approach you should specify the margin for the node to do the positioning, e.g.

```
StackPane.setMargin(node, new Insets(20, 0, 0, 100));
```

To place the `Node` at distance 20 from the top and at distance 100 from the right.

---

If you don't want the `StackPane` to position a child, you can set managed to `false` for this child:

```
node.setManaged(false);
node.setLayoutX(100);
node.setLayoutY(20);
```

Note that this way `node` will be treated as if it isn't there where layout is concerned.

Comment: thanks fabian ,, one question thou, can i set managed to false and still add nodes to center ? because i have been adding nodes to the stack pane then setting the translate x and y ,,, thanQ